# Parse thousands of xml files with awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have several thousand files and they each contain only one very long line.

I want to convert them all to one file with one entry per line split at the ID fields and I have this working with a few files but it takes too long on hundreds of files and seems to crash on thousands of files. Looking for a faster way that is unlimited.

```
(find -type f -name '*.xml' -exec cat {} \;) | awk '{gsub("ID","\nID");printf"%s",$0}'
```

I have also tried this..

```
(find -type f -name '*.xml' -exec cat {} \;) | sed 's/ID/\nID/g'
```

I think the problem is trying to use replacement instead of insertion or it is using too much memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it with thousand of files, but instead of `cat` all data into memory before processing them with `awk`, try to run `awk` with some of those files at a time, like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml*" -exec awk '{gsub("ID","\nID");printf"%s",$0}' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks guys. My pipe is flowing through now. I feel like I have unlocked the secret to the universe.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list of all files you need to process
2. Divide this list into smaller lists each including 50 files
3. Create a script that reads a sub-list and outputs an intermediate file, 
      doing the ID thing also
4. create another script that executes the script in 3, 20 process at a time, as many as necessary, as background processes
5. merge the output files